# How to get the answer of a mathematics operation

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I am coding a calculator in Angular.js 7 but I cant get the answer when I operate the code.

This is a calculator program and user can enter 2 value and choose an operator button to decide the operator, after that user need to click = button to get answer.

calculator.component.html

```
<div class="calculator">
  <h1>Calculator</h1>
  <div>
    <input ng-model="num1" type="text" placeholder="Enter value">

    <p><span><input type="text" readonly value={{selectedOperator}}></span></p>
    <p><input class="num2" type="text" placeholder="Enter value">
      <button class="result" (click)=onSelectEqual()>=</button>

      <span><input type="text" readonly value={{answer}}></span></p>

    <button class="operator" (click)=onSelectAdd() ng-init='+'>+</button>
    <button class="operator" (click)=onSelectMinus() ng-init='-'>-</button>
    <button class="operator" (click)=onSelectTimes() ng-init='*'>*</button>
    <button class="operator" (click)=onSelectDivide() ng-init='/'>/</button>
  </div>
```

calculator.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';


import { Operator } from 'rxjs';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-calculator',
  templateUrl: './calculator.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./calculator.component.css']
})
export class CalculatorComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }




selectedOperator='';
onSelectAdd(){
  this.selectedOperator = '+';
}
onSelectMinus(){
  this.selectedOperator = '-';
}
onSelectTimes(){
  this.selectedOperator = '*';
}
onSelectDivide(){
  this.selectedOperator = '/';
}


num1:string = '';
num2:string = '';
answer = '';

onSelectEqual(){
  if (this.selectedOperator = '+') //here is function to get answer, but when I operate this I can only get operator'+' which I dont want answer button can change operator.//
  this.answer = this.num1 + this.num2 ;
}


}
```

Comment: Please check https://github.com/GadhiyaAkash/simple-calculator to get caculator logic in Angular. Also you will learn some additional items.

Comment: i think you missing ng-model="num2" in code so that why it is not working

Comment: you should go for triple equals here: `if (this.selectedOperator === '+')`

Comment: Set a breakpoint into the onSelectEqual method and see what happens.

Comment: I have a problem which is unable to fetch user input of num1 and num2. How can I get user input in the num1 and num2 textarea?